# How to pipe an output of a list as the input of grep in Linux?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a `table_1`

```
A D G
B E H
C F I
```

I print the column 1 of the above table using `awk '{print $1}' table_1` to get `list_1`

```
A
B
C
```

I want to use `list_1` above to `grep -f` from `table_2`

```
A n m
B m n
C n m
D m n
E n m
```

to get `table_3`

```
A n m
B m n
C n m
```

but I want to do it using a one-liner, not needing to save an intermediate file of `list_1`.

How can I structure the command?

Comment: `grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' table_1) table_2`?

Comment: Is it save to assume that `A` or any search term can't be part of any other column of `table_2`? Maybe you should add a `^` before and a whitespace after your search terms.

Answer (score 3):

A trivial (but *not* bash-specific) variation on [Cyrus’s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421143/80216#comment757317_421143):

```
awk '{print $1}' table_1 | grep -f - table_2
```

which uses the widespread convention that a filename of **`-`**
means “read from the standard input”.

Comment: but this is not so robust... grep will search any where in the line and would even match part of column...

Comment: Where does the question specify which behavior is desired? The question says that the OP’s current workflow is to create the temporary `list_1` file and use it (implicitly, in ```grep -f list_1 table_2```), and asks how to streamline that operation into a “one-liner” with no temporary file.  It doesn’t say that the OP wants to use the values from column 1 of `table_1` to match against the values from column 1 of `table_2`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($1 in a)' table_1 table_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another way to use `join`. 
If the files are sorted, and `table_2` really has only three columns,
you can use

```
join -o "2.1 2.2 2.3" table_1 table_2 > table_3
```

As [Kusalananda says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421143/80216#421156),
`join` is a program that exists specifically to combine two files
by matching values from one column of the first file
against values from one column of the second file. 
By default, if uses the first column of each file (you can override this). 
By default, it combines the matching lines, like this:

```
$ join table_1 table_2
A D G n m
B E H m n
C F I n m
```

The `-o "2.1 2.2 2.3"` says “output the first field of the second file,
and then the second field of the second file,
and then the first third of the second file
(but nothing from the first file<sup>1</sup>)”. 
Unfortunately, there don’t seem to be any shortcuts, shorthands,
accelerators, or wildcards here;
there’s no way to say “output the entire line from the second file”. 
If the second file has many fields,
then the `-o` format will have to be very long.

This differs from the `grep`-based solutions (yours and [mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421143/80216#421150))
in that it specifically matches the values from column 1 of `table_1`
against the values from column 1 of `table_2`,
and will not give you lines from `table_2`
that have an `A` in column 2 or column 3, or an `AZ` in column 1. 
`join`, like `grep`, recognizes a `-i` (`--ignore-case`) option,
so, if the first line of `table_2` is `a n m` (with a lower-case `a`),
you will get that line in your `table_3` output
if (and only if) you specify `-i`.
________
<sup>1</sup> Except for the first field of the first file —
which is the same as first field of the second file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both tables are sorted on the first column, and using a shell like `bash` or `ksh93` that understands process substitution with `<(...)`:

```
$ join <( awk '{ print $1 }' table_1 ) table_2
A n m
B m n
C n m
```

If the tables are *not* sorted, then we need to sort them:

```
$ join <( awk '{ print $1 }' table_1 | sort ) <( sort table_2 )
A n m
B m n
C n m
```

The `join` utility performs a [relational INNER JOIN operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) on the first column (by default) of the two files that you give it.

Redirect the output to a new file to create `table_3`:

```
$ join <( awk '{ print $1 }' table_1 | sort ) <( sort table_2 ) >table_3
```